# KendoTreeView inside Kendo Grid Table

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-treeview, kendo-treelist

I need to utilize the functionality of kendo treeView's kendoTreeViewCheckable for every node in KendoTreeList.

Is there any option to do or is there any way to use KendoTreeView inside Kendo Grid Table like KendoTreeList?

[image: suggest checkable functionality of every node like below or how to render this KendoTreeView inside KendoGrid Table]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/treelist/configuration/columns.selectable

e.g.

```
$("#treelist").kendoTreeList({
  columns: [
    { selectable: true, width: 65 },
    { field: "id", width: 250},
    { field: "name", width: 250 },
    { field: "age", width: 250}
  ],
  dataSource: [
      { id: 1, parentId: null, name: "Jane Doe", age: 31, city: "Boston" },
      { id: 2, parentId: 1, name: "John Doe", age: 55, city: "New York" }
  ]
});
```

This adds a checkbox column to every node.